# unable to Fetch date and time from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

I am trying to fetch the time and date from the text  FOX News  October 27, 2022 5:00pm-6:00pm PDT, but not getting a standard approach. While using the position of the string, it doesn't work because the size of the string changes with the different months (April to December) and times.

```
text=['FOX News  October 27, 2022 5:00pm-6:00pm PDT'
'FOX News  April 28, 2022 10:00pm-11:00pm PDT']
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(text)),columns =['text'])
df['text'].str[-20:]

output 

22 5:00pm-6:00pm PDT

How can I improve the code to get generalise results in two different columns(date and time)?
```

Comment: If the string always starts with `"FOX News  `, just index from the beginning instead of the end: `df['text'].str[10:]`

Comment: is text a list that is missing the comma or something else?

Comment: @JasonBaker as with the different months, the length of string changes so it don't give correct restuls

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to extract the dates:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
text=['FOX News  October 27, 2022 5:00pm-6:00pm PDT','FOX News  October 28, 2022 5:00pm-6:00pm PDT']
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(text)),columns =['text'])
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(parser.parse, fuzzy=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df['text']
0   2022-10-27 17:00:00-06:00
1   2022-10-28 17:00:00-06:00
Name: text, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzoffset(None, -21600)]
```